# What is the proper virt-install location url to use for ubuntu when installing via http?

Tags: system-installation, repository, kvm-virtualization, virt-manager, netinstall

I'm trying to install Ubuntu in a vm using Virtual Machine Manager.

[image: Create a new virtual machine]

I do however get the following error which leads me to believe that I have not pointed to the correct url.

[image: unable to identify os]

Manually selecting `Ubuntu 20.04 LTS` as the operating system lets me answer a few more questions - but eventually it fails anyway.

[image: invalid repo url]

I've read the `virt-install` manual which states:

```
   -l, --location
       Syntax: -l, --location OPTIONS

       Distribution tree installation source. virt-install can recognize certain distribution trees and fetches a bootable kernel/initrd pair to launch the install.

       --location  allows  things  like --extra-args for kernel arguments, and using --initrd-inject. If you want to use those options with CDROM media, you can pass the ISO to --location as well which works
       for some, but not all, CDROM media.

       The LOCATION can take one of the following forms:

       https://host/path
              An HTTP server location containing an installable distribution image.

       ftp://host/path
              An FTP server location containing an installable distribution image.

       ISO    Extract files directly from the ISO path

       DIRECTORY
              Path to a local directory containing an installable distribution image.  Note that the directory will not be accessible by the guest after initial boot, so the OS installer  will  need  another
              way to access the rest of the install media.

       Some distro specific url samples:

       Fedora/Red Hat Based
              https://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/releases/29/Server/x86_64/os

       Debian https://debian.osuosl.org/debian/dists/stable/main/installer-amd64/

       Ubuntu https://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/wily/main/installer-amd64/

       Suse   https://download.opensuse.org/pub/opensuse/distribution/leap/42.3/repo/oss/

       Additionally,  --location  can  take  'kernel' and 'initrd' sub options. These paths relative to the specified location URL/ISO that allow selecting specific files for kernel/initrd within the install
       tree. This can be useful if virt-install/ libosinfo doesn't know where to find the kernel in the specified --location.

       For example, if you have an ISO that libosinfo doesn't know about called my-unknown.iso, with a kernel at 'kernel/fookernel' and initrd at 'kernel/fooinitrd', you can make this work with:

          --location my-unknown.iso,kernel=kernel/fookernel,initrd=kernel/fooinitrd
```

From that I've derived that `https://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/main/installer-amd64/` should be a valid url - but it does not work.

I've clicked deeper into the folder structure and hoped/guessed that the url I attempted in the pictures would be good (i.e. `https://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/main/installer-amd64/current/legacy-images/netboot/ubuntu-installer/amd64/`) but the behavior is the same.

What is the url supposed to be? Is this no longer a working feature?

Comment: Two things you might want to look into: The URL `http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/main/installer-amd64/` doesn't seem to be available over an encrypted connection, so maybe you need to use `http://` instead of `https://` for this one. Also, at least in [this tutorial](https://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/host-virtual-machines-on-ubuntu-with-virt-manager/), they use an URL pointing to an ISO file. I don't have the time right now to work out a full-fledged answer, but those two points seem worth looking into to me.

Answer (score 0):

Installing from a downloaded ISO works.

Drop TLS and it works for focal: http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/main/installer-amd64

Jammy seem to have completely restructured the installer so I'm still unable to figure out which url to use for it.

http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy/main/installer-amd64/current/legacy-images/index.html states

> Try the New Ubuntu Server Installer

> The Legacy Ubuntu Server Installer is no longer available.